# How to separate data in SQLSRV

Tags: php, sqlsrv

Maybe this is a silly question but until now i don't know how to solve it. I have a table and it show in date format.

```
05 Mar 2020
07 Mar 2020
12 Mar 2020
14 Mar 2020
02 Apr 2020
04 Apr 2020
09 Apr 2020
11 Apr 2020
02 May 2020
09 May 2020
14 May 2020
16 May 2020
```

From this output, how can i separate it by Month? Example like below :

[image: month]

I know how to show the output but i don't know how to separate it

```
$result2 = sqlsrv_query($conn1, $query1);
while ($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result2)) {

        echo "$row2[0]<br>";
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is your SQL statement (`$query1` variable)?